# trouble logging in to Udemy from my Windows 10 laptop

Tags: vpn, android

I have a Dell laptop with Win10. I'm trying to login to my Udemy account. When I login from my Android device, it logs in just fine. However, when I try to login from PC with the same credentials, it says that there's a problem with my email or password. I should mention that Udemy is banned in my country and I'm using VPN to access it on both my Android and PC. Thank you for your help